# Need Help Making a "python" Program - How do i get my select menu to start the diffrent conversions when i given an input (1 or 2)

Tags: python

Ive been working on this tempeture converter but have been troubling conbining the two programs (Celsius to Fahrenheit) and (Fahrenheit to Celsius), i can get the display menu to print but cant manage to figure out how to select a converter.

```
# Tempeture Converter
def convert():
    print 'Conversions Menu';
    print '(1) Celsius to Fahrenheit';
    print '(2) Fahrenheit to Celsius';

def select():
    convert();
    choice = input ('Enter Choice Number:')
    if (input == '1'):
        C2F();
    elif (input == '2'):
        F2C();

def F2C():
    Fahrenheit = input('enter degrees in Fahrenheit: ');
    Celsius    = ( 5.0 / 9.0) * (Fahrenheit -32); 
    print Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit =', Celsius, 'Celsius';

def C2F():
    Celsius    = input('enter degrees in Celsius: ');
    Fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * Celsius +32;
    print Celsius, 'Celsius =', Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit';
```

****Correction****

```
# Tempeture Converter
def convert():
    print 'Conversions Menu';
    print '(1) Celsius to Fahrenheit';
    print '(2) Fahrenheit to Celsius';

def select():
    convert();
    choice = input ('Enter Choice Number:')
    if (choice == '1'):
        C2F();
    elif (choice == '2'):
        F2C();

def F2C():
    Fahrenheit = input('enter degrees in Fahrenheit: ');
    Celsius    = ( 5.0 / 9.0) * (Fahrenheit -32); 
    print Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit =', Celsius, 'Celsius';

def C2F():
    Celsius    = input('enter degrees in Celsius: ');
    Fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * Celsius +32;
    print Celsius, 'Celsius =', Fahrenheit, 'Fahrenheit';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`, `input` will try to wrap whatever you type in `eval` to convert it to Python code, so when you enter '1' or '2' it will be converted to an integer, but you are still trying to compare to strings.

Combine that with what Paul mentioned about `choice` instead of `input` and you should have a working solution.

Also, drop all of the semi-colons and the parentheses in your conditionals, they aren't necessary in Python:

```
def select():
    convert()
    choice = raw_input('Enter Choice Number:')
    if choice == '1':
        C2F()
    elif choice == '2':
        F2C()
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the program to rerun after i use the converter...
so once i convert F2C i get the menu again?

Comment: @enrique2334 If you found a valid solution you should accept an answer. Also, you would have to use a while loop to be able to do another conversion after the initial one.

Answer (score 2):

In the `select` function, you have

```
choice = input('...')
```

but then you check

```
if (input == '1'):
    ...
```

that second `input` should be `choice`. The same thing applies to the `elif(input == '2'):` statement. Again `input` should be replaced by choice. Or alternatively you can use `raw_input` with `'1'` and `'2'` as J.F. suggested.

Furthermore the `input` function automatically converts `1` and `2` to integers, so you should really check `if (choice == 1)` and similarly for `2`.

Finally you will need to have some form that actually runs the `select()` function, like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    select()
```

Comment: I edited my answer (convert `'1'` to `1` and introduce if __name__ .. form), now it should run as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have the program to rerun after i use the converter... so once i convert F2C i get the menu again?

The simplest way is to wrap the `select()` function in a loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
      select()
```

And then in the `select()` function maybe add an option to exit:

```
elif choice == '3':
  exit()
```

Comment: Glad to help.  You should accept one of the answers you got (but not mine, because the others were more helpful) by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.